# Select asterisk from table but if the value is negative turn into positive

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    Info varchar(50) null,
    Col1 int null,
    Col2 int null,
    Col3 int null,
    Col4 int null,
    Col5 int null
);
```

Is there a way?

Comment: You mean `select *... `?

Comment: Yes, but turning negative integers into positives

Comment: You can't really use * and do that. Also, using * is almost always bad practice.

Comment: Like `Math.abs(*)` I think.. is it possible?

Comment: What would you expect for the `ABS` of the varchar column then?

Comment: If this is something that you will need in multiple places, you may want to make a view against the table so the view always returns positive numbers.

Comment: @Ghost. How can I do that?

Comment: That is a new question, but I suppose I can answer it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using * you can use `ABS`:

```
SELECT Info, ABS(Col1) as Col1...
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't manipulate individual fields when you're querying `*`, you'd have to handle each field individually and apply [`abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) to it:

```
SELECT info, ABS(col1), ABS(col2), ABS(col3), ABS(col4), ABS(col5) 
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a view, you can re-use that logic over and over easily by selecting against the view instead of the table.

```
CREATE VIEW MyTablePositiveNumbers AS
    SELECT
        Info,
        ABS(Col1) Col1,
        ABS(Col2) Col2,
        ABS(Col3) Col3,
        ABS(Col4) Col4,
        ABS(Col5) Col5
    FROM MyTable;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, it may be useful later

Answer (score 1):

use function abs, that returns always absolute values
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800%28v=sql.120%29.aspx